# blocking the installation of a certain app android

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to create an app to block the installation of a certain app based on the package name. I tried the BroadcastReceiver method but the app seems to crash. and thank you for reviewing this and for the help.

here is my BroadcastReceiver class:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    Context context;
    String log = MyReceiver.class.getName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        this.context = context;
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED")){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Package removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(log,"Package removed");
        }
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED")){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Package installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(log,"Package installed");
        }
    }
}
```

manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name="MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
            <data android:scheme="package"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
```

crash log:

```
10-12 22:18:22.836 15429-15429/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver, PID: 15429
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver.MyReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver.MyReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3287)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1719)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver.MyReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.mohammed.broadcastreceiver-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3282)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1719) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: I don't understand how receiving when an app is installed lets you block it. Also, if you want help with a crash, you have to include the crash log.

Comment: no I am just testing with that. I was trying with this at first then when it works and I see the Toast I will try another block of code. but for now I will include the crash log and I appreciate your concern.

Comment: @TheWanderer here i just included the crash log with the edit

Comment: Is MyReceiver in a sub-folder?

Comment: @TheWanderer oh yeah that was the main issue. I didn't pay attention to that. thanks a lot for your help

Comment: "I am trying to create an app to block the installation of a certain app based on the package name" -- by the time `PACKAGE_ADDED` is broadcast, the app is already installed.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to block the installation of apps. That's not something a regular app can do. To do this you'd need to modify package manager in Android and build your own distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've registered your Receiver incorrectly.

The crash log says it can't find MyReceiver in the root of your project (which is where you've said it exists in your Manifest), but it looks like it isn't.

Make sure the `name` attribute points to the actual location.

Comment: Yeah thank you, the file was in a sub folder i just changed it's location and now the app works